# How to use Windows 10 OpenSSH ssh-agent service with Cygwin?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, ssh-agent

I'm using the Visual Studio Code [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension on a Windows 10 laptop to access a bunch of Linux development servers.  I followed these [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent) to set up the Windows built-in [ssh-agent service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement), which is basically a few lines in an Administrator PowerShell terminal...

```
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service ssh-agent
Get-Service ssh-agent
```

This allows me to run `ssh-add` from a Command Prompt to install a private key, after which `ssh`, `scp`, `sftp` etc can connect to the remote host without needing the key passphrase, as can VSCode itself.

I also have Cygwin installed on the laptop, so my question is: how do I configure it so that those instances of the OpenSSH programs can access the Windows ssh-agent service?  I guess there's a magical setting for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` but how do I find out what it is?  Yes, I could use [keychain](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/keychain.html) to load keys into a Cygwin-hosted `ssh-agent` process, but that means I have to type all the passphrases twice.

For now I've simply uninstalled the OpenSSH package in Cygwin so that bash runs the Windows version of `ssh` etc from `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH`, but I'd like to do it properly instead.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Uninstalling Cygwin OpenSSH isn't a good solution after all because it messes up Emacs Ange-FTP - the ssh commands Tramp uses don't work with the Windows version of command-line programs.

Comment: Have you figured this out? It's not just Cygwin, but also the SSH command that Git-Bash distributes that would benefit from this...